# spring batch add job parameters in a step

Tags: spring-batch

I have a job with two steps. first step is to create a file in a folder with the following structure

```
src/<timestamp>/file.zip
```

The next step needs to retrieve this file and process it

I want to add the timestamp to the job parameter. Each job instance is differentiated by the timestamp, but I won't know the timestamp before the first step completes. If i add a timestamp at the beginning of the job to the job parameter then each time a new job instance will be started. any incomplete job will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make use of JobExecutionContext instead.

Step 1 gets the current timestamp, use that to generate the file, and put to JobExecutionContext.  Step 2 read from the JobExecutionContext to get the timestamp, which used to construct the input path for its processing.

Just to add something on top on your approach of splitting steps like this: You have to think twice whether this is really what you want.  If Step 1 finished, and Step 2 failed, when the job instance is re-runed, it will start from Step 2, that means the file is not going to regenerate in Step 1 (because it is completed already).  If it is what you look for, that's fine.  If not, you may see if you want to put Step1 & Step2 in one step instead.